# Override method with specific implementation class?

Tags: java, interface

Is it possible to override a class, but provide a specific implementation that must be provided if the overridden method is directly called on this method (and not on an super interface)?

```
class BaseService implements BaseInferface {

    //something like this?
    @Override //implements the interface
    void run(<? extends BaseDTO) dto) {

    }
}

class CustomService extends BaseService {
    //CustomDTO extends BaseDTO
    @Override
    void run(CustomDTO dto) {

    }
}
```

My goal is:

```
baseService.run(new BaseDTO()); //OK
customService.run(new BaseDTO()); //NOK as I want to make the CustomDTO required
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
interface BaseInterface<T extends BaseDTO>
{
    void run(T dto);
}

class BaseService<T extends BaseDTO> implements BaseInterface<T>
{
}

class CustomService extends BaseService<CustomDTO>
{
}
```

Comment: OK nice. Is it possible to provide a "default" implementation `BaseDTO`, so that my custom services do not necessairly have to provide a type parameter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Maybe `interface BaseDTOInterace extends BaseInterface<BaseDTO>`?

Comment: I mean: `CustomService extends BaseService`, omitting the type parameter should "chose" a default implementation eg of `BaseDTO`.

Comment: Well, create a `class BaseDTOService implements BaseInterface<BaseDTO>` (or `extends BaseService<BaseDTO>`)